# Why does using this global `operator<<` fail to compile?

Tags: c++

Here is the interface in a nutshell

```
#include <iostream>

struct Graph
{
    typedef int Parameter;

    struct Render
    {
        void to (std :: ostream &) {}
    };

    Render render (Parameter) {}
};

std :: ostream &
operator << (std :: ostream &, Graph :: Render &);

int main ()
{
    Graph () .render (0) .to (std :: cout);

    // std :: cout << Graph () .render (0);
}
```

The above will compile without complaint, unless you uncomment the last line.

Why doesn't the global `operator<<` compile?

Comment: Do you implement `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Graph::Render&);` anywhere in your program?

Comment: For the benefit of others, that would be a link error, not a compile error, but thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have overloaded your operator only for mutable lvalues, so the prvalue (the temporary value that is `Graph().render(0)`) does not bind to it.

You can either change your operator overload to use a const reference (which will accept lvalues *and* rvalues):

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, const Graph::Render &);
//                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or you can add an additional rvalue overload:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, Graph::Render &&);
//                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If in doubt, go with the first solution. It would be extremely surprising if printing a string representation of the object would require its mutation.

(It is also kind of weird that `Graph::render` should return a new `Render` object by value, but that's your decision.)